# Functional Vue Component with Typescript - Access Methods

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to convert a functional component to typescript. I can`t find any information on how to access methods on that component in the template though. The Variety of ways to declare components doesn't help either. In the non-ts version you could easily access methods via "$options", but with ts "$options" does not seem to exist on "vm", thats what the error-message says at least. What would be the correct syntax here?

```js
<template functional>
  <button @click="$options.func">Click Me</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
@Component({})
export default class Foo extends Vue {
  private func = () => console.log("yolo")
}
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work even in plain JS. A functional component has no instance, and `$options` does not exist on the context object.

Comment: Very true, I just realized that I added the method to the root of the vue component and then accessd it via $options. That probably was a hacky workaround anyway, no wonder I don't find an "equivalent" for ts (it still works in ts, but obviously there is now an error popping up that that "option" is not expected). Anyway, probably restructure my code. Thanks